# Determine whether or not can an array of numbers can be divided into two arrays, with each array holding the same sum of numbers

Tags: java, loops, iteration

Below is a code to determine whether or not can an array of numbers can be divided into two arrays, with each array holding the same sum of numbers.
for example: {1, 3 ,2, 6} can be divided into {6} and {1,2,3}, therefore return true
while {1,5,7} can't be divided into two, balanced array, therefore return false

```
public boolean canBalance(int[] nums) {
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) { 
       int sum = 0;
       for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) sum += nums[j];
       for (int j = i; j < nums.length; j++) sum -= nums[j];
       if (sum == 0) return true;    
    }    
    return false;
}
```

it's an accepted answer for an exercise in codingbat, I don't understand this piece in particular:

```
for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) sum += nums[j];
for (int j = i; j < nums.length; j++) sum -= nums[j];
```

doesn't for iteration usually starts with { and ends with } ? 
and how come if sum == 0 means it can be balanced?
I have tried noting it down on piece of paper with array of {1,3,2,6} and had sum of 26, which returns false, where it's obvious that {1,3,2,6} should return true.

I think I misread the code, I don't know which, though. Or maybe the algorithm is false, but it was accepted in codingbat

Comment: Can't understand what is your problem

Comment: Use a debugger. You will understand it better.

Comment: `for` loops (among other branching constructs) often use `{ }` braces for clarity, correctness, or necessity.  But they are not strictly required when used with a _single_ statement line.

Comment: If you have just one statement inside your for-loop, you can ommit the curly braces. The same is valid for do, while, if and else. However, it is considered good coding practice to use { and } even in these cases.

Comment: The for loops only have the one statement. The var `i` is the position to split, the two for loops inside add (in the first loop) and subtract (in the second loop) the numbers either side of the split position - if the total equals zero, you can split at that point.

Comment: What is the expected outcome in situations like {1,3,5,7}? The above code would return false, but a division is possible: {1,7} and {3,5}.

Comment: @Henry that's why I'm confused. because the code was accepted in codingbat as correct code.

Comment: @TheLostMind what is a debugger and how can I use it?

Comment: @Rei - are you using some kind of an IDE like *eclipse/ netbeans* to write this code?

Comment: Hi, I don't your code is right. What you are describing is the 'Partition Problem'. See this link for more info:[Partition Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem)

Comment: @TheLostMind no. it was an answer I found in the internet, for a particular codingbat exercise. the answer was accepted as a correct answer. However, I can't see how this code is correct, because I tried noting it down on paper with the same algorithm, and like Henry said, sometimes the code would return false, where it should be true instead

Comment: @Rei - [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger) explains debuggers. It is a tool used to see how your program executes and states of variables.

Comment: @AlvinBunk holy moly there's even a wikipedia page for this .__. thanks. I'll check it out

Comment: To save you some time in coding and debugging, take the sum of all the numbers and then divide by 2 (if not divisible by 2, then you can't create the partitions). Then you can have two partitions that each add up to half the sum.

Comment: However, if the sum of all numbers is divisible by 2, it **doesn't** mean it can be separated into 2 partitions. The total of {1,7,8,10} is 26 and is divisible by 2. However, you cannot make 2 groups of 13 from there.

Comment: Seems like [this is the original problem from CodingBat](http://codingbat.com/prob/p158767). The reason this particular snippet is accepted because we don't know what are their exhaustive test cases.

Comment: @AndrewT. yes, it's a problem from codingbat. what do you mean 'because we dont know what are their exhaustive test cases' ?

Comment: Don't mind my previous comment. I just re-read the original problem, and it seems you missed the important keyword *"Given a non-empty array, return true if there is **a place to split the array** so that the sum of the numbers on one side is equal to the sum of the numbers on the other side. "* (emphasis mine). In other words, this is a more specialized version of partition problem.

Comment: @AndrewT. what does that mean actually? sorry I'm not a native english speaker, isn't that only asked if it's actually possible to divide the array?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The two for-loops are for weighing the two parts of the array, to find the **array balancing point** of an array.

Think of it like this:

You have a empty balance scale, in the first iteration of the outer for loop, i is zero.

It comes to first for loop, here j is 0 and i is 0 `i < j` is false, *so it doesn't enter the first for-loop and it goes into the second for-loop and subtracts all the numbers from sum.*

From second iteration onwards of the outer for-loop, it starts entering the first for-loop and
starts adding the elements of the array one-by-one to the sum.

In pictures, it is like starting with an empty balance scale, adding all the elements into the second scale, and moving one by one element to the first scale, like this:

[image]

In the end, if the sum is zero, then the array can be balanced, so return true. If the sum isn't 0, it's unbalanced.

The values in the are balanced by the loops like this:

**Iteration of outer for loop when i is 0**
Loop 2 -> i(0) j(0) Subtract 1, sum is -1
Loop 2 -> i(0) j(1) Subtract 3, sum is -4
Loop 2 -> i(0) j(2) Subtract 2, sum is -6
Loop 2 -> i(0) j(3) Subtract 6, sum is -12

**Iteration of outer for loop when i is 1**
Loop 1 -> i(1) j(0) Add 1, sum is 1
Loop 2 -> i(1) j(1) Subtract 3, sum is -2
Loop 2 -> i(1) j(2) Subtract 2, sum is -4
Loop 2 -> i(1) j(3) Subtract 6, sum is -10

**Iteration of outer for loop when i is 2**
Loop 1 -> i(2) j(0) Add 1, sum is 1
Loop 1 -> i(2) j(1) Add 3, sum is 4
Loop 2 -> i(2) j(2) Subtract 2, sum is 2
Loop 2 -> i(2) j(3) Subtract 6, sum is -4

**Iteration of outer for loop when i is 3**
Loop 1 -> i(3) j(0) Add 1, sum is 1
Loop 1 -> i(3) j(1) Add 3, sum is 4
Loop 1 -> i(3) j(2) Add 2, sum is 6
Loop 2 -> i(3) j(3) Subtract 6, sum is 0

**Final result is true, therefore the array can be balanced**

### Code:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] test = { 1, 3, 2, 6 };
        System.out.println("\nFinal result is "+canBalance(test));
    }

    public static boolean canBalance(int[] nums) {
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("\nIteration of outer for loop when i is " + i);
            int sum = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++){
                sum += nums[j];
                System.out.println("Loop 1 -> i(" +i + ") j("+j + ") Add "+nums[j] + ", sum is "+sum+"       ");
            }
            for (int j = i; j < nums.length; j++){
                sum -= nums[j];
                System.out.println("Loop 2 -> i(" +i + ") j("+j + ") Subtract "+nums[j] + ", sum is "+sum+"       ");
            }
            if (sum == 0)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

---

### If you want to allow shuffling between the elements of the array, you can use recursion as follows (comments are self-explanatory)

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] original = { 10, 2, 24, 32 };
        System.out.println(canDivideArray(original));
    }

    private static boolean canDivideArray(int[] originalArray) {
        int total = 0;

        for (int number : originalArray) {
            total += number;
        }

        // check if sum == 2x for any value of x
        if (total % 2 != 0) {
            return false;
        } else {
            // sum of each half array should be x
            total /= 2;
        }
        return isTotal(originalArray, originalArray.length, total);
    }

    private static boolean isTotal(int array[], int n, int total) {
        // successful termination condition
        if (total == 0) {
            return true;
        }
        
        // unsuccessful termination when elements have finished but total is not reached
        if (n == 0 && total != 0){
            return false;
        }

        // When last element is greater than total
        if (array[n - 1] > total)
            return isTotal(array, n - 1, total);

        //check if total can be obtained excluding the last element or including the last element 
        return isTotal(array, n - 1, total - array[n - 1]) || isTotal(array, n - 1, total); 
    }

}
```

Comment: yes, but if I tried using 1,3,2,6 the sum won't be 0, while 1,3,2,6 can be divided into two balanced arrays. it means there's flaw in the logic right?

Comment: hi, I tried using 1, 3, 2 and it doesn't work. it returns with a false, where it should be possible to divide it to {1,2} and {3}

Comment: No @Rei, then you misunderstood array balancing concept. You can search "array balancing point of an array" and see in any search engine and see. Balancing means in the array, if there is any point where all the elements on the left side are equal to the sum of all the elements on the right side of that point, then it is balanced. Here, order of the elements is very important. 1,3,2 is unbalanced, because in that order, there is no point where you break the array and get to arrays of equal sum.

Comment: The array is considered a linear arrangement, i.e. a sequence, it's not a jumbled set of random elements. If jumbling is allowed, then in that case, it will be a permutation and combination problem, not a balancing problem.

Comment: I wanna ask about permutation and combination thingy, but I guess that's out of the scope of this thread. thanks, that answered my question :D

Comment: @Rei: I added the shuffling using recursion and explained in comments, it is indeed out of scope, but I added it because it adds more value to this post for future users too :)

Answer (score 1):

If reordering of the elements of the array is not allowed, we just have to find the split point in the given array. The solution in the question does this by trying all possible split points and checking if the sum of the two parts is equal. It has effort that is quadratic in the length of the input array.

Note that it is easy to come up with solutions that have linear effort, for example the following snippet. It builds sums of the elements on the left side and on the right side of array, in each step the smaller sum is increased by adding an array element. This is repeated until the parts meet.

This assumes that the array does not contain any negative numbers.

```
public boolean canBalance(int[] nums) {
  int sumL = 0, sumR = 0;
  int l = -1, r = nums.length;
  while (r - l > 1) {
    if (sumL < sumR) {
      sumL += nums[++l];
    } else {
      sumR += nums[--r];
    }
  }
  return sumL == sumR;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a recursive solution to the problem, one non recursive solution could use a helper method to get the sum of indexes 0 to a current index in a for loop and another one could get the sum of all the elements from the same current index to the end, which works. Now if you wanted to get the elements into an array and compare the sum, first find the point (index) which marks the spilt where both side's sum are equal, then get a list and add the values before that index and another list to go after that index.

Here's mine (recursion), which only determines if there is a place to split the array so that the sum of the numbers on one side is equal to the sum of the numbers on the other side. Worry about indexOutOfBounds, which can easily happen in recursion, a slight mistake could prove fatal and yield a lot of exceptions and errors.

```
public boolean canBalance(int[] nums) {
  return (nums.length <= 1) ? false : canBalanceRecur(nums, 0);   
}
public boolean canBalanceRecur(int[] nums, int index){ //recursive version
  if(index == nums.length - 1 && recurSumBeforeIndex(nums, 0, index) 
  != sumAfterIndex(nums, index)){ //if we get here and its still bad
  return false;
  }
  if(recurSumBeforeIndex(nums, 0, index + 1) == sumAfterIndex(nums, index + 1)){
  return true;
  }
  return canBalanceRecur(nums, index + 1); //move the index up
}
public int recurSumBeforeIndex(int[] nums, int start, int index){
   return (start == index - 1 && start < nums.length) 
   ? nums[start] 
   : nums[start] + recurSumBeforeIndex(nums, start + 1, index);
}

public int sumAfterIndex(int[] nums, int startIndex){
  return (startIndex == nums.length - 1) 
  ? nums[nums.length - 1] 
  : nums[startIndex] + sumAfterIndex(nums, startIndex + 1);
}
```

//non recursively

```
public boolean canBalance(int[] nums) {
   for(int a = 0; a < nums.length; a++) {
      int leftSum = 0;
      int rightSum = 0; 
      for(int b = 0; b < a; b++) {
      leftSum += nums[b];
      }
      for(int c = a; c < nums.length; c++) {
      rightSum += nums[c];
      }
      if(leftSum == rightSum) {
      return true;
      }
   }
   return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess 'dividing' in the original question does not allow re-ordering of the array. So, you simply break the array at a particular position, and we will have the left side and the right side of the array. Numbers in each side should have the same sum.

The index (i) of outer loop is the breaking position.

```
for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
```

The first inner loop sums the left side of the array.

```
for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) sum += nums[j];
```

The second inner loop subtracts elements of the right side from the sum of the left array.

```
for (int j = i; j < nums.length; j++) sum -= nums[j];
```

If the final result is zero, it means the sum of left side and right side is the same.
Otherwise, continue the outer loop and examine other breaking position until we find the right breaking position.

Answer (score 0):

Approaching this problem with DP solution.

//Create a 2D array and fill in bottom up manner
//DP[totalsum / 2 + 1] [ length of array + ]

```
bool divisible(int arr[], int size)
{
int sum = 0;

// Determine the sum 
for (i = 0; i < size; i++) sum += arr[i];

if (sum%2 != 0) return false;

bool DP[sum/2+1][size+1];

// initialize top row as true
for (i = 0; i <= size; i++)
    DP[0][i] = true;

// initialize leftmost column, except DP[0][0], as 0
for (i = 1; i <= sum/2; i++)
    DP[i][0] = false;     

 // Fill the partition table in botton up manner 
 for (int i = 1; i <= sum/2; i++)  
 {
     for (int j = 1; j <= size; j++)  
     {
         DP[i][j] = DP[i][j-1];
         if (i >= arr[j-1])
             DP[i][j] = DP[i][j] || DP[i - arr[j-1]][j-1];
     }        
 }    
 return DP[sum/2][size];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as **@Alvin Bunk** said in the comment, the answer you give in the question itself is not a good answer, it works differently even if the order of elements is changed in the array.

You should check this wiki for the theory & implement it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a standalone method to sum parts of an array and used this in my solution to get the simplest method I can see possible. If anyone has any comments, please join in. I appreciate the comments.

```
//Create a method that gets the sum from start to the iteration before end.
public int sumArray (int[] nums, int start, int end)
{
  //Create a sum int that tracks the sum.
  int returnSum = 0;
  //Add the values from start (inclusive) to end (exclusive). In other words i : [start, end)
  for (int i = start; i < end; i++)
  {
    returnSum += nums[i];
  }
  return returnSum;
}

//This is our main class.
public boolean canBalance(int[] nums) {
  //If nums has an actual value, we can work with it.
  if (nums.length > 0)
  {
    //We check to see if there is a value that is equal by using the sumArray method.
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++)
    {
      //If from [0,i) the value equals from [i, nums.length), we return true;
      if (sumArray(nums, 0, i) == sumArray(nums, i, nums.length))
      {
        return true;
      }
    }
    //If we finish the loop, and find nothing, we return false;
    return false;
  }
  //If there is no value, we return false.
  else
  {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

When there aren't any curly braces around around code after a for statement in Java, the very next line is the only line processed as part of the for statement.  In this case, the for is like a function that calls the next line of code, which is a for statement that then calls the next line of code.  So the first for calls the second for which evaluates to see if the two sides are the same, and if they aren't then it kicks back up to the second for which continues incrementing itself until it finishes and then it returns to the first for, which increments, and calls the second for... and so on.  That code seems like it's partially broken, though, since it would have to have all numbers in numeric order, and it doesn't check anything in the middle.

For instance:
`{1, 2, 3, 1} //evaluates to true because 1-1=0, although it should be false`
`{6, 2, 2, 3} //evaluates to true because 6-3-2=0, although it should be false`
`{2, 3, 4, 6} //evaluates to true because 2+3-6=0, although it should be false`